# calling flash using javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

I searched ExternalInterface but didnt got to know, how to implement it.

I want to run/execute a flash when clicked on an image element.

```
<img src="a.png" onclick="runFlash()" />
```

my Flash

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="16" HEIGHT="16" id="flashUpload" ALIGN="">
 <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="{swf_upload_url}?UploadSession={upload_session}&AccessKey={AccessKey}&ServerID={ServerID}&ShowTopBtn=1&TopBtnIcon={SKIN_DIR}/images/a.png">
 <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
 <PARAM NAME=allowScriptAccess VALUE=always>
 <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#000000>
 <PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE=transparent>
 <EMBED src="{swf_upload_url}?UploadSession={upload_session}&AccessKey={AccessKey}&ServerID={ServerID}&ShowTopBtn=1&TopBtnIcon={SKIN_DIR}/images/a.png" quality=high bgcolor=#000000  WIDTH="32" HEIGHT="32" NAME="flashUpload" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

Can you please help me with a detail example?

I tried placing an image above the flash with absolute position but when clicked the flash doesn't run.

Thank You.

Regards,

Shishant Todi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [SWFObject](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/) and put something like this in your runFlash() function:

```
var so = new SWFObject("movie.swf", "mymovie", "400", "200", "8", "#336699");
so.write("flashcontent");
```

And just put a div on the page named "flashcontent" which initially contains the image.

Comment: It actually embeds the flash replacing image i want to run the flash when clicked on image.

Comment: ok so you can just put the image somewhere else, and the flash will still get loaded into the "flashcontent" div.

Answer (score 0):

That's how your AS3 should look like:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("runFlash", jsCallsRunFlash);

function jsCallsRunFlash()
{
    ...
}
```

**//edit**

And [here's AS2 version tutorial](http://blog.deconcept.com/2005/08/16/external-interface/)